# NoClassDefFoundError on HelloWorld program

Tags: eclipse, java, noclassdeffounderror

I've looked through the other NoClassDefFoundError questions and not found a solution that works for me. I'm using the Eclipse IDE to write a program, and it runs fine when I right-click -> Run as Java application in Eclipse, but attempting to run it through the command line runs into the above error. The JRE I'm using is (I think) Java60. The program is compiled using javac HelloWorld.java which runs fine, then a call to java -cp . HelloWorld throws the error. Any help with troubleshooting this would be much appreciated.

Code is:

```
package tool;

public class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
}

}
```

Running from "C:\MADtool\HostDBtoMADTool\src\tool"

Output from the command line is:

```
C:\MADtool\HostDBtoMADtool\src\tool>java -cp . HelloWorld
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld (wrong nam
e: tool/HelloWorld)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Post the exact exception stacktrace and your dir structure

Comment: Show your HelloWorld.java file here.

Comment: can you post your code? It would be good to rule that out first :)

Comment: Are you  running your java command from a folder where your class is in?

Comment: Have you tried just "java HelloWorld" ?

Comment: Is your workspace of eclipse is in same location?

Comment: read [***this***](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html) & [***this***](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1702894/1066828)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You enter the package "tools" and make a javac (which is correct), but then you try to start the class from within that package folder (what is wrong).

You have to change to the src-directory first, because the classpath is relative to the source-folder. If you use packages (what you really should do). You must ensure to start your code from the correct start-folder:

```
C:\MADtool\HostDBtoMADtool\src>java -cp . HelloWorld
```

**update**
Take a look at classpath definitions: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29)

Comment: This helped me to get it to work! I changed to the src directory and ran `java -cp . tool/HelloWorld` and it worked! Thanks, can you tell me why what I was doing was wrong so I can make sure I don't make the same mistake in the future? I read the link and I can kind of understand it, but I don't see how being a directory level up sorted it.
P.S. Your closing parenthesis didn't add onto the end of your link for some reason

Comment: I changed a little bit in my answer. But you should google for more information about creating **.jar** files and building java project. Hint: search for **ant** or **maven**

Answer (score 2):

Executing `$ java HelloWorld` will search for class `HelloWorld` in the **default package**. No such class exists, there is only `tool.HelloWorld`.

Additionally, if you run `$ java tool.HelloWorld`, then java will try to find the file `tool/HelloWorld.class`, so you need to make sure that your working directory is the directory that **contains** `tool/`, **not** `tool/` itself.

Answer (score 0):

from my very old expirience from comand line i compile my java program:

```
javac MyClass.java
```

Then try to run it parsing compilen class param with extention:

```
java MaClass.class
```

Then I get this exception. When I just parse file name without extention it works:

```
java MyClass
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing some dependencies in your classpath?

I mean that your HelloWorld class may depende on other jars that should be included in the classpath.
Eclipse does it for you, but using the command line you have to provide the appropiate classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I think the full command always help when problems occur:

```
C:\MADtool\HostDBtoMADtool\src>java -cp "C:\MADtool\HostDBtoMADtool\src" tool.HelloWorld
C:\MADtool\HostDBtoMADtool\src\tool>java -cp "C:\MADtool\HostDBtoMADtool\src" tool.HelloWorld
```