# Why am I getting a ClassNotFoundException in a java application?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am getting an error that states, `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: usemathobject/Main` and I'm not sure why I'm getting it.

After doing some searches, I found a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702852/the-dreaded-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror) that deals with this error.   In that thread, it says I need to modify the MANIFEST.MF file, but it doesn't explain clearly to me how to modify that file. It specifies what to put on the command line but not what to put in the `MANIFEST.MF` file. I also tried adding

```
Main-Class: "C:\Users\MyName\Documents\NetBeansProjects\UseMathObject\src\usemathobject\UseMathObject.java"
```

to `Manifest.mb`, as suggested on https://blogs.oracle.com/olaf/entry/jdev_including_a_classpath_in but that didn't work.

I am using `NetBeans IDE 6.9.1` on `Windows Vista`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Main-Class: usemathobject.UseMathObject
```

You give the package and the class name, not the file path.

Comment: How do you start your application?

Comment: I opened up NetBeans from the Windows start menu. Then I clicked the "Clean and Build Main Project" button, and then I clicked the "Run Main Project" button.

Comment: The class that contains your `public static void main` method is inside a class called `UseMathObject` which is in a package called `usemathobject`, yes? Bear in mind that CaPiTaLiZaTiOn is important here. Perhaps you could provide a stripped-down version of your main class in code?

Comment: Yes, I have "public static void main(String[] args)" inside the class "UseMathObject". I have no idea how to tell what my package is called.

Comment: Well, what is the first line in your `UseMathObject.java` file?

Comment: I just added "package usemathobject;" to my main file as well as another file with classes that I used. However, now it is telling me it cannot find certain symbols in my file.

Comment: Remove the package again. And change your mainfest file to say: `Main-Class: UseMathObject`

Comment: I removed the package from both files, and edited the manifest file, and I still got "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: usemathobject/Main"

Comment: I got it working by changing the file to "Main.java" and renaming the UseMathObject class to Main. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to set entry point for stand-alone applications bundled into executable jar file. The use of the below option creates or overrides the Main-Class attribute value in the manifest file. This option can be used during creation of jar file or while updating the jar file. This option specifies the application entry point without editing or creating the manifest file.

For example, this command creates Main.jar where the Main-Class attribute value in the manifest is set to Main:

> jar cfe Main.jar Main Main.class

The java runtime can directly invoke this application by running the following command:

> java -jar Main.jar

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem here is that you do not **understand** what you are doing, you are randomly trying things that people are telling you ... without understanding what they are saying means.  And you are not understanding what the error messages are telling you.

I think you would be better off trying to **understand** how Java's package, classpath and jar file mechanisms work.  Read the following sections of the Oracle Tutorials:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html

Once you've read and understood these sections, it will all make sense ... and you will be able to figure out what you are doing wrong and how to fix it.