# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils

Tags: java, android, exception, jar, noclassdeffounderror

I m working on a project which is working great on a machine but on another machine having OS WINDOW 8 when I run same project I got Exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils
```

It is related to runtime class path but I dont know from where I need to set that. External jar is used here and there is no error in any of file.

Please Suggest

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702852/the-dreaded-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror

Comment: Maybe your external library is not exported to your apk, I suggest you to see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16841050/could-not-find-class/16841371#16841371

Comment: @Gustek I searched many question. But no answer works for me. So If you know how to rectift then please go forward.

Comment: Go back to your old machine and check CLASSPATH, make sure it's set the same on your new machine.

Comment: @VarunVishnoi: I have done that you said. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the last version of the ADT eclipse plugin (mine is 22.0.0.v201305140200--675,183), there are problems with external libraries and a common mistake remembers: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.
To solve this problem you can follow the link in which I give a solution: [Could not find class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16841050/could-not-find-class/16841371#16841371)

Answer (score 1):

This error because of your **.jar** file. Add your jar file in libs folder look at this solution we will solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/12511271/964741